# Redux how to trigger a rerender when adjusting the values of a map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am currently trying to create a map that links a string to an object with 2 values stored within it and use redux so that it is available globally. Ex:

```
  "QUYfCMXJtLe5X4nmA0IY" => Object {
    "like": false,
    "saved": false,
  },
```

My issue right now is that when i update the map it doesn't trigger a rerender.

here is my reducer:

```
function likesAndSavedReducer(state = likesAndSaved, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'replaceAllLikesAndSaved':
      return Object.assign(state, action.payload)
    default:
      return state;
  }
```

heres how I import and try to to render the data:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        likesAndSaved: state.likesAndSavedReducer
    };
  };

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        replaceAllLikesAndSaved: lastPost => dispatch(actions.replaceAllLikesAndSaved(lastPost)),
    };
};

const FeedLook = (props) => {
    //updates the map with new value of liked and has a similar function to set like: false
    const likeIt = (item, index) => {
        const likes = props.likesAndSaved
        if(likes.has(item.id)){
            likes.set(item.id, {like: true, saved: likes.get(item.id).saved})
        } else{
            likes.set(item.id, {like: true, saved: false})
        }
        props.replaceAllLikesAndSaved(likes)
    }

    // this gets rendered in the renderItem of a flatlist
    {props.likesAndSaved.has(item.id)
        ?
            props.likesAndSaved.get(item.id).like
                ?
                <AntDesign name="heart" size={24} color="red" onPress={() => unLikeIt(item, index)}/>
                :
                <AntDesign name="hearto" size={24} color="black" onPress={() => likeIt(item, index)}/>
        :
            <AntDesign name="hearto" size={24} color="black" onPress={() => likeIt(item, index)}/>
       }
)
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(FeedLook);
```

I know that the function works because if i reload the page the button is correctly highlighted. I am just confused on how to get it to rerender on updated redux state. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Please show how it's used in the flatlist. Where does the function `likes.set` come from? Are you sending functions through redux?

Comment: Likes.set is because it is a hashmap i can set a new id => object pairing within the hashmap. This is all done locally and then the updated hashmap once it has been set is passed to redux.

Comment: Use an immutable update instead. You shouldn't ever mutate your props. React will only rerender if the object reference has changed, it has no idea if the data has mutated.

Comment: thx switched to immutable and everything worked

Answer (score 0):

After switching to immutable.js everything is working fine.
Here is my reducer with initial value

```
import {Map} from 'immutable'
const likesAndSaved = new Map()

function likesAndSavedReducer(state = likesAndSaved, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'updateObj':
      return state.set(action.payloadId, action.payloadData)
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

and how it gets called:

```
const FeedLook = (props) => {
    //updates the map with new value of liked and has a similar function to set like: false
    const likeIt = (item, index) => {
        let likes = {}
        if(props.likesAndSaved.has(item.id)){
            likes = {like: true, saved: props.likesAndSaved.getIn([item.id, 'saved'])}
        } else{
            likes = {like: true, saved: false}
        }
        props.updateObj(item.id, likes)
    }

    // this gets rendered in the renderItem of a flatlist
    {props.likesAndSaved.has(item.id)
        ?
            props.likesAndSaved.getIn([item.id, 'like']) === true
            ?
                <AntDesign name="heart" size={24} color="red" onPress={() => unLikeIt(item, index)}/>
                :
                <AntDesign name="hearto" size={24} color="black" onPress={() => likeIt(item, index)}/>
        :
            <AntDesign name="hearto" size={24} color="black" onPress={() => likeIt(item, index)}/>
    }
)
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(FeedLook);
```

Comment: Similarly, your reducer should return a new object as well. When you're moving data around in react and redux, avoid mutation everywhere.

Comment: Hi I know its much later but im just starting to understand mutability and i was wondering what you meant by your statement above. I created another question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69893050/question-on-best-practices-immutability-and-re-rendering-with-react-native) and was wondering if you could check it out or expand a bit more about what you meant above here. Thx